# Search through multiple directories for files PHP

Tags: php

New to php. I need to search through multiple directories on an ftp server and download files contained in them according to their date (which is contained in each file's name). So far I am running into issues with Array to string conversion - hopefully you can see what I am "trying" to do here and might be able to help me out.

```
<?php
$url = ' MY FTP SERVER';
$user = ' USERNAME '; 
$pass = ' PASSWORD';

$target = 'LOCAL DIRECTORY';


$connection = ftp_connect($url) or die ("Could not connect to $url");
$loginBool = ftp_login($connection, $user, $pass);
    if ($loginBool)
    {
        echo "Connected as $user at $url";
    }else{
        echo "Could not connect as $user";
    }
ftp_chdir($connection, 'MOVE ONE FOLDER IN');
$ftpDirectories = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");
for($i=0; $i < (count($ftpDirectories)); $i++){
    $directory = ("/MAIN DIR/$ftpDirectories[$i]/");
    echo $directory;
    ftp_chdir($connection, $directory);
    echo ftp_nlist($connection, $directory);
    }

?>
```

**The logic, as I see it, works as follow:**

Get a listing of all folders under the main folder which is stored in Array

Loop through each element of the array(folders on the ftp)and change into the directory

one by one

Print out the files (so I know its working)

**What I still need to add:**

After changing into a directory split the filenames into an array and compare them to

today's date -> download if the filenameDate[index] == today's date

**THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!**

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$url = 'pmike86.zxq.net';
$user = 'pmike86_zxq'; 
$pass = '******';

$target = 'C:\Folder\\';


$connection = ftp_connect($url) or die ("Could not connect to $url");
$loginBool = ftp_login($connection, $user, $pass);
    if ($loginBool)
    {
        echo "Connected as $user at $url";
    }else{
    echo "Could not connect as $user";
    }
ftp_chdir($connection, 'HW');
$ftpDirectories = ftp_nlist($connection, ".");
for($i=0; $i < (count($ftpDirectories)); $i++){
    $directory = ("/HW/$ftpDirectories[$i]/");
    echo $directory;
    ftp_chdir($connection, $directory);
    foreach (ftp_nlist($connection, $directory) as $item) 
    { 
    ftp_get($connection, $target, $item, FTP_BINARY); 
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: [`ftp_nlist()` returns an array](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) but you are trying to `echo ftp_nlist()` and PHP is then complaining about converting the array to a string for echo output. If you want to inspect the contents, use something like `print_r(ftp_nlist($connection, $directory);`

Comment: You could also loop them individually `foreach (ftp_nlist($connection, $directory) as $item) { echo $item; }` may be closer to your described intent _Print out the files so i know its working_

Comment: As I am looping through to change directories how can I add the array index as a string? - So I can say /Main Dir/folder 1 then /Main Dir/folder 2 -> which is what I am trying to accomplish by using  $directory = ("/MAIN DIR/$ftpDirectories[$i]/"); in which case I will change into that directory.. (sorry if im not explaining well)

Comment: Assuming you don't have multiple levels of directory nesting, what you already have with `$directory = ("/MAIN DIR/$ftpDirectories[$i]/")` in the for loop looks like it would work.  The `foreach` I suggested would be for the innermost as a replacement for `echo ftp_nlist()`  Can you post a sample of the directory contents, and a sample of which of those files should ultimately be downloaded?

Comment: I left an edit in the original post - I had to just make a fake ftp real quick so that you could see what I am attempting to do. I would need to download every text file you see throughout the directories (which are set up appropriately for my main issue). I ended up re-reading your comment and placed the foreach loop in the correct position and now get some failures but it was a step in the right direction! and for that I am really grateful!

Comment: just curious if you've considered accomplishing this task with rsync or rdist?